# I have an excel file and I would like to know which formulas are repetitive and iterative... the links to these sheets are also all over the place

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

The excel file has 30+ sheets and formulas everywhere. I tried tallying the formulas but it's not giving me the results that I wanted since C2 in one sheet is not necessarily C2 in another, despite the formulas containing them being the same.

for example:

Sheet 1 has this on cell A1:
`=IF($C$2 ="DOG",I19,SUMIFS($D$19:$E$19,$D$20:$E$20,$D$21:$E$21))`

and Sheet 2 has this on cell A1:
`=IF($C$2 ="DOG",I19,SUMIFS($D$19:$E$19,$D$20:$E$20,$D$21:$E$21))`

since they are matching, i would want to know if their values are the same since the cells in the formula are the same.

TLDR I have a stock pricing model excel file that I think is too heavy. I would want to find redundant computations within the file.

Comment: This is very unclear without sample data and explanation on that

Comment: Replied, I hope it clarifies it

Comment: Still not clear - if the referenced cells in the formula contain different values then there's a good bet the results of the formula will be different.

Comment: @dragon95: is my answer solving your issue or not?

Answer (score 0):

The values will not be the same: the formulas contain cell references, but the mentioned cell references refer to the worksheet they are located in: the formula in sheet "Sheet1" refers to the cells in "Sheet1", while the formula in sheet "Sheet2" refers to the cells in "Sheet2".

In case you want the formula in "Sheet2" refer to the cells in "Sheet1", you need to mention this in the cell references, something like (not tested):

```
=IF(Sheet1!$C$2 ="DOG",Sheet1!I19,SUMIFS(Sheet1!$D$19:Sheet1!$E$19,Sheet1!$D$20:Sheet1!$E$20,Sheet1!$D$21:Sheet1!$E$21))
```